# html wont go to css and therefore will not change colors

Tags: html, css

I have below for my code. It is posting it on my entire webpage instead of just on that image and I can't quite figure out why.

```css
dt {
  font: Arial, Helvectica, sans-serif;
  size: .9em;
  weight: bold;
  color: (dark red (#6b1101);
  line-height: 2em;
}

dd {
  font: Arial, Helvectica, sans-serif;
  size: .9em;
  weight: bold;
  color: (dark red (#6b1101);
  line-height: 2em;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #F7EED7;
}

#imgtop {
  width: 700px;
}

#leftnav {
  background-color: #F7EED7;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

#leftnav a:link {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000033;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  display: block;
}

#leftnav a:visited {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans=serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #660066;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  display: block;
}

#leftnav a:hover {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000033;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#maintext {
  background-color: #F7EED7;
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>Cafe Townsend: Wine Tasting Terms </title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cafe.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<div id="leftnav">
  <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
  <p><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></p>
  <p><a href="location.html">Location</a></p>
  <p><a href="RestaurantInfomation.html">Restaurant Infomation</a></p>
  <p><a href="ResturantReview.html">Restaurant Review</a></p>
  <p><a href="specialevents.html">Special Events</a></p>
  <p><a href="dvd.html">DVD</a></p>
  <p>
    <a href="wine-list.html">
      <img src="../images/wine_header.jpg" alt="Wine Ad" width="150" height="100" border="0" /></a>
  </p>
</div>
<p>Greeting: &quot;Hello, World!&quot;</p>
<h1>Knowing your wines</h1>

<dl>
  <dt>Acid, acidity</dt>

  <dd>The tart (or in excess, sour) quality that wine's natural acidity imparts and that gives the wine a sense of body and structure. Required for proper balance; too much or too little constitutes a flaw.</dd>

  <dt>Almond</dt>

  <dd>A light bitter, nutlike quality sometimes noted in Italian white wines.</dd>

  <dt>Anise</dt>

  <dd>Faint licorice, a pleasant element in some Spanish reds; may indicate, however, that the wine has been artificially acidified, a practice that may improve short-term enjoyment but tends to make wines that cellar poorly.</dd>

  <dt>Attack</dt>

  <dd>A technical term for the first impression the wine makes as it reaches your palate, distinguished (in time sequence) from &quot;middle&quot; or &quot;"mid-palate"&quot; and &quot;finish&quot; or &quot;aftertaste.&quot;</dd>

  <dt>Bouquet, bottle bouquet</dt>

  <dd>As a technical term, the smells that develop with age in the wine bottle, as opposed to &quot;aroma,&quot; the smells associated with the fruit. I have little use for distinctions this narrow and try to avoid using them in my wine notes.</dd>
  <dt>Earthy</dt>

  </dd>Generic term for a range of aromas and flavors associated with organic qualities like &quot;barnyard,&quot; &quot;forest floor,&quot; &quot;merde,&quot; and &quot;tree bark.&quot; May be associated with brettanomyces (see above) but can also result
  from oak aging or the nature of specific grapes. Mourvedre, for instance, imparts a characteristic earthy aroma. Again, not necessarily a fault, but &quot;earthy&quot; wines tend to be controversial, and a little bit is usually enough.</dd>
</dl>
</body>

</html>
```

So for some reason my html is not getting the dt and dd and changing the colors from normal to red. I dont get it, it goes to file (it should) but is doing nothing. have tried checking file names, making sure the paths are correct (they are). They are in the same exact folder.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other CSS file attached that is overriding this? Try adding an !important just to test. something like color: red !important;

Comment: It is the only CSS I have created so far for this.

Comment: Take out weight:bold, that is breaking it. It should be font-weight:bold

Comment: That did it, thank you!!

Comment: No worries, can you give my reply the tick please if it solved it.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Elements are not correctly nested and some opening tags are missing. Also `color: (dark red (#6b1101);` is not valid CSS for `color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the weight: bold; This is breaking the CSS below. It should be font-weight:bold.

```
font-dd {font: Arial, Helvectica, sans-serif;
size: .9em;
font-weight: bold;
color:red;
line-height: 2em; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to use a value that is not a valid color `(dark red (#6b1101)` is not correct. Find the available value types here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp